# LokiJS simpleSort issues

Tags: lokijs

I have a need to sort my data based on the property set in LokiJS simpleSort.
Its a string data type which contains both numeric & floating point values.

Example :

```
var db=new loki('example.db');
var users = db.addCollection('users');
users.insert([{ name: '1391046.1141', age: 35}, { name: '20111', age:30},{ name: '1391050.1141', age: 35}, { name: '20031', age: 30}]);
//users.insert([{ name: '1391046.1141', age: 35}, { name: '1391036.1141', age: 30},{ name: '1391046.1140', age: 35}, { name: '1391056.1141', age: 30}]);
var results=users.chain().simplesort('name',true).data();
```

// logText('Results');
logObject(results);
  inspectObject(db)

Comment: Provide some code please

Comment: Please let me know if further details needed.Its just a straight forward query

Comment: sort is not proper with line 3, however with line 4 input data sort works fine